# Which calculator will be useful here?

Tags: self-learning, factoring, calculator

I want to factor the denominator of this expression $\frac{1}{bu^2-2au-b}$ so that I get this expression $-\frac{b}{(-bu+\sqrt{b^2+a^2}+a)(bu+\sqrt{b^2+a^2}-a)}$.

I used hp 50g calculator with COLLECT, FACTOR , SIMPLIFY commands but all vain attempts. I also tried online simplication, factoring calculator but couldn't get the desired mathematical expression.

Would any member suggest me any calculator which will be useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the equation $$bu^2-2au-b=0$$ by the quadratic formula we get
$$u_{1,2}=\frac{a}{b}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+1}$$ so you can write
$$b(u-u_1)(u-u_2)$$